# Unit tests for a custom Date Serializer

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have recently started writing tests in Java and I am having some problem with the tests for the following class. How to write correctly tests for TestDateTimeSerializer class in such a form.

```
public class TestDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
    public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime dt, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        if (dt == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
        } else {
            gen.writeString(dt.format(FORMATTER));
        }
    }
}
```

this class is used here

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
public class TestRequest implements ITestResponse {
    @JsonProperty("TestID")
    private Long testID;
    @JsonSerialize(using = TestDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `JsonGenerator` as mock object, then verify its method call.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestDateTimeSerializerTest {
    @Mock
    JsonGenerator generator;       // JsonGenerator is mock
    @Mock
    SerializerProvider provider;

    @Test
    void test() throws IOException {
        TestDateTimeSerializer serializer = new TestDateTimeSerializer();
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        
        // run your method
        serializer.serialize(now, generator, provider);

        // assert mocked generator's method call
        verify(generator).writeString(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());
    }
}
```

Mockito API doc : https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1

you can find more example and usage.

Comment: Mock isn't appropriate here. A serializer is quite a simple object and you can test all the branches of if-else directly. Furthermore, ArgumentMatchers.anyString() will hide potential problems. For example, you can change the string of FORMATTER and your test will not fail. That's not how tests should be designed.

Comment: Thanks, it works. One thing only missing from your answer. The class and methods should be public. Otherwise there will be an error org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.

Comment: @dimirsenZ. I know that this is not perfect example. I used anyString() cause just it is simple and easy to understand. Making it match his own case is another issue.

Comment: Min Hyoung Hong with all due respect I don't think that they are separate issues.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestDateTimeSerializerSerializerTest {

        private ObjectMapper mapper;
        protected TestDateTimeSerializer serializer;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            serializer = new TestDateTimeSerializer();

            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, serializer);
            mapper.registerModule(module);
        }

        @Test
        public void testSerializeNonNull() throws JsonProcessingException {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-10-06T10:40:21.124", ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);

            String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(ldt);

            assertEquals("equal strings", "\"2016-10-06T10:40:21.124Z\"", serialized);
        }

        @Test
        public void testSerializeNull() throws JsonProcessingException {
            LocalDateTime ldt = null;

            String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(ldt);

            assertEquals("equal strings", "null", serialized);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately your test for null does not cover the code. The test itself is of course passed but in Jacoco's report this part of code is not covered.

Comment: This piece of code should be covered. 
 if (localDateTime == null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeNull();
        }

Comment: please vote for my answer and we will solve this issue ;)

Comment: You can also vote for my main question

Comment: Voted. So, there is no sense in having if (localDateTime == null) branch in the serializer. Null value has no type and your application just doesn't know which serializer to trigger. I tried to adapt the test and pass (LocalDateTime)null - cast to a particular type, but Intellij even shows that this cast has no sense. If you search for examples of serializers say on github, you won't find braches with null checks. Null values are handled with annotations, please read http://www.javabyexamples.com/control-how-jackson-serializes-null-values